# how do I define an object of a class inside its class?

Tags: c++

I am trying to define an object of mylist inside the mylist class.

here is my code:

mlist.h

```
#ifndef MLIST_H
#define MLIST_H

#endif // MLIST_H

#include "mylist.h"

template <class T> class mlist
{
protected:
    T item = 0;
    mylist<T> next = 0;
};
```

mylist.h

```
#ifndef MYLIST_H
#define MYLIST_H

#include "mlist.h"

template <class T> class mylist : mlist<T>
{
private:
    T item;
    mylist<T>* next;

// --- some functions ---

};

#endif // MYLIST_H
```

the error:

> error: 'mylist' does not name a type
>
> mylist next = 0;

my question: What is going wrong and what is the correct way on doing this?

Comment: Forward declarations.

Comment: @Jashaszun No, that wouldn't work.

Comment: @juanchopanza Ah yes. I didn't read the question completely.

Comment: A class containing itself is logically impossible; something which only an M.C. Escher painting could accurately depict :)

Comment: Having a object of type `T` inside type `T` would create infinite nesting and lead to an object of infinite size. It is not possible to physically nest an object into itself. All you can do is perform indirect nesting, i.e. store a pointer or a reference to `T` inside `T`.

Comment: Seems a circular reference malfunctioned. Try putting your `#endif` in the bottom-most of the file.

Answer (score 1):

You can't define a concrete object of a class inside its definition because at the time the compiler sees the objects definition it knows nothing about its class.

You can however define a pointer to an object of the same class inside the class's definition.

Also your code suffers from the problem of circular dependency.

Now, in order to solve this you have to forward declare `template class mylist` before the definition of `template class mlist`. If you do this however, you introduce another problem, that is you can't have a concrete object of `class mylist` inside the definition of `class mlist`. Again this is solved by defining a pointer to an object of `class mylist` inside the definition of `class mlist`:

```
template<class T> class mylist;

template <class T>
class mlist {
protected:
  T item;
  mylist<T>* next;
};

template <class T>
class mylist : mlist<T> {
  T item;
  mylist<T>* next;
};

int main() {
  mylist<int> lst;
  (void) lst;
}
```

### [**LIVE DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4f53d1e360c5c9bb)

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to define an object of mylist inside the mylist class.

Actually this is not everything you try to do. You try to have a `my list` member both in `mylist` and `mlist`. I think you try to use something which does not exist in C++ - pure virtual members. The lines

```
protected:
 T item = 0;
 mylist<T> next = 0;
```

Look like you intended it. The also cause mutual dependency between `mlist` and `mylist` because you try to have `mylist` member in `mlist`, and you try to derive `mylist` from `mlist`.

Remove the lines I quoted above and your compilation error should be gone.